# Возникшая проблемам привела к прекращению работы программы

Tags: c++, qt, while

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять почему программа вылетает без ошибок.
Переделал её и она теперь состоит из пары файлов:
mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDialog>
#include <string>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    double Ckrt,Ttr,Tv,U,U1,dT,D,H,H1,Mmp,V1,W,wv,Ww,nu,A,amp,acc,arz,F,MBB;
    double wg,k2,Ct,Mt,tmax,Vmax,omega,Ron,Xiz,Xizu,XXiz,a1,zst,Cmpu,Cccu,Crzu;
    double isd,omH,f1,Vm,Vm1,fe,m,n,dh,Um,m1,Xm,Cmp,Ccc,Cmpd,Cccd,Crzd,P,R,Xmu;
    double X,X1,kX,S1,Kmp,Kcc,Krz,X11,kXu,X2,S11,Kmpu,Kccu,Krzu,Kiz,kmpi,XXizu,zn;

    double Ps,U0,U2,Y,Y1,tym,ty2m,S2m,ty,ty2,S2,Si,Smax,Xmin,Xmax,Ymin,Ymax,Xminu,Xmaxu,Yminu,Ymaxu;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_radioButton_clicked();

    void on_radioButton_2_clicked();

    void on_radioButton_3_clicked();

    void on_radioButton_4_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString _KPT;
    double _Mkrt;
    int j,NN,gr;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

и файла mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

#include <math.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <iostream>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()

{
    _Mkrt=1000;
    tmax = 1;
    Ttr = 30;
    Tv =10;
    U = 2;
    H = 12;
    Ww = 8000;
    a1 = 2;

    Ron=800;wv=21.2E-6;amp=1.2;
    acc=1.2;arz=300;
    Ps=0.13332*exp((5.596-1394.72/(204.26+Ttr))*2.3026);
    wv=40.42*Ps*1e-6;

    W=Ww/3600;
    dT=abs(Ttr-Tv);
    D=0.62;
    V1=W;
    F=1;
    omega=4*W/(M_PI*D*D);
    nu=1;

    Si=1000*_Mkrt/Ron;
    Smax=170;
    Vmax=800;
     if (Si>Smax) {
         Si=Smax;
     }
     if (NN==1) {
         Mt =Si*wv*tmax*3600*1000;
         if (Mt>_Mkrt*1000) {
             Mt =_Mkrt*1000;
         }
         Ckrt=Mt/Vmax;
         Mmp=Ckrt*V1;
         amp=1.2; acc=1.2; arz=300;

     } else if (NN==2) {
         k2=0.542;  wg=60e-3;
         Mt=Si*wg*tmax*3600*1000;
         if (Mt>_Mkrt*1000) {
             Mt=_Mkrt*1000;
         }
         Ckrt =k2*Mt/Vmax;
         Mmp =Ckrt*V1;
         amp=3; acc=1; arz=20;

     } else {

     }

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    A =200;
    omH=omega/H;
    if (dT<=5) {dT=5;}
    f1 = 1000*D*omH*omH/dT;
    Vm = 0.65*exp(log(V1*dT/H)/3);
    Vm1 = 1.3*omH*D;
    fe =800*Vm1*Vm1*Vm1;
    if (f1<100){
        if (f1>fe){
            m =1/(0.67+0.1*sqrt(fe)+0.34*exp(log(fe)/3));
        } else {
            m =1/(0.67+0.1*sqrt(f1)+0.34*exp(log(f1)/3));
        }
        if (Vm>=2) {
            n=1; dh =7*sqrt(Vm)*(1+0.28*exp(log(f1)/3)); Um =Vm*(1+0.12*sqrt(f1));
        } else if (Vm<0.5) {
            m1=2.86*m;
            n=4.4*Vm;
            dh=2.48*(1+0.28*exp(log(fe)/3));
            Um=0.5;
        }else{
            n=0.532*Vm*Vm-2.13*Vm+3.13;
            dh=4.95*Vm*(1+0.28*exp(log(f1)/3));
            Um=Vm;
        }
    } else {
          if (Vm1>=0.5) {
              m=1.47/exp(log(f1)/3);
          }
          if (Vm1<0.5) {
              m1=0.9;
          }
    }
    if ((f1>=100) || (dT<10)) {
        if (Vm1>=2) {
            n=1;
            dh=16*sqrt(Vm1);
            Um=2.2*Vm1;
        }
        else if (Vm1<0.5) {
            n=4.4*Vm1;
            dh=5.7;
            Um=0.5;
        }
        else {
            n=0.532*Vm1*Vm1-2.13*Vm1+3.13;
            dh=11.4*Vm1;
            Um=Vm1;
        }
    }

    Xm =(5-F)*dh*H/4;

    if (((f1>=100) && (Vm1>=0.5)) || (dT<10)) {
        Cmp=a1*A*Mmp*F*n*nu*D/(8*V1*exp(4*log(H)/3));
    } else {
        if (Vm<0.5) {
            Cmp=A*Mmp*F*m1*nu/exp(7*log(H)/3);
        } else {
            Cmp=a1*A*Mmp*F*m*n*nu/(H*H*exp(log(V1*dT)/3));
        }
    }

    Ccc=Cmp;
    if (amp<0) {amp=1E29;} if (acc<0) {acc=1E29;} if (arz<0) {arz=1E29;}

    Cmpd=Cmp/amp; Cccd=Ccc/acc; Crzd=Cmp/arz;

    if (U==Um) {
        U=Um+0.0001;
        U1=U/Um;
    }
    if (U1<=0.25) {
        P=3;
    } else {
        if (U1>1) {
            P=0.32*U1+0.68;
        } else {
            P=8.43*exp(5*log(1-U1))+1;
        }
    }

    Xmu=P*Xm;

    if (U1>1) {
        R=3*U1/(2*U1*U1-U1+2);
    } else {
        R=0.67*U1+1.67*U1*U1-1.34*U1*U1*U1;
    }

    Cmpu=R*Cmpd; Cccu=R*Cccd; Crzu=R*Crzd;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //Блок расчёта значений функции Конц = f(X)

    X=zn;j=1;
    double *aX = new double[j];
    double *aKmp = new double[j];
    double *aKmpu = new double[j];
    aX[0]=zn;
    aKmp[0]=0;
    aKmpu[0]=0;
    while (j<1000) {
        aX[j]=X/1000;
        X1=X/Xm;
        if (X1<=1) {
            S1=3*X1*X1*X1*X1-8*X1*X1*X1+6*X1*X1;
        }
        if ((X1>1) && (X1<=8)) {
            S1=1.13/(0.13*X1*X1+1);
        }
        if (X1>8) {
            if (F<=1.5) {
                S1=X1/(3.58*X1*X1-35.2*X1+120);
            } else {
                S1=1/(0.1*X1*X1+2.47*X1-17.8);
            }
        }
        if ((X1<1) && (H<=10)) {
            S1=0.125*((10-H)+(H-2)*S1);
        }

        Kmp=S1*Cmpd; Kcc=S1*Cccd; Krz=S1*Crzd;

        X11=X/Xmu; X2=X11*X11;
        if (X11<=1) {
            S11=3*X2*X2-8*X2*X11+6*X2;
        } else {
            if (X11<=8) {
                S11=1.1/(0.1*X2+1);
            } else {
                if (X11<=24) {
                    S11=2.55/(0.13*X2+9);
                } else {
                    if (X11<=80){
                          if (F<=1.5) {
                                     S11=X11/(4.75*X2-140*X11+1435);
                           } else {
                                     S11=2.26/(0.1*X2+7.41*X11-160);
                                   }
                    } else {
                         if (F<=1.5) {
                             S11=X11/(3.58*X2-35.2*X11+120);
                         } else {
                             S11=1/(0.1*X2+2.47*X11-178);
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
         }

        Kmpu=S11*Cmpu; Kccu=S11*Cccu; Krzu=S11*Crzu;



        aKmp[j]=Kmp; aKmpu[j]=Kmpu;



        X=X+zst;  j+=1;
    }

}



void MainWindow::on_radioButton_clicked()
{
    NN=1;
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_2_clicked()
{
    NN=2;
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_3_clicked()
{
    zn=2; zst=10; gr=3;
}

void MainWindow::on_radioButton_4_clicked()
{
    zn=1000; zst=10; gr=4;
}
```

Что бы её запустить достаточно добавить две кнопки и 4 радио батона :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вылетает она, когда считает точки для графика в цикле

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
//Блок расчёта значений функции Конц = f(X)
while (j<1000) {...}
```

Но почему мне не понятно. Точки считаются и она выходит из этого цикла.

Comment: Для этого есть отладчик.

Comment: от такого и у отладчика голова закружится (шутка).   Для хранения такого количества данных лучше использовать контейнеры, и соответственно не будут столько имен...

Comment: Не пишите расчеты в "кнопках". Все вычислительные функции вынесите в отдельные функции, протестируйте их, а потом уже наворачивайте сверху GUI. Плюс расчеты делать в GUI потоке плохая практика.

Comment: скиньте что ли проект на гитхаб, а то очень лень собирать из ваших кусочков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив имеет размер 1 элемент, потому и выбивает

```
X=zn;j=1;
double *aX = new double[j];
double *aKmp = new double[j];
double *aKmpu = new double[j];
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да долго провозился но j=1000; помогла решить проблему)