# Как правильно создать три динамических массива?

Tags: c++, qt

Создаю динамический массив: `double *aX = new double [j];` и создаю сразу еще один и второй:

```
double *aKmp = new double [j];
double *aKmpu = new double [j];
```

И после создания второго динамического массива программа вылетает с ошибкой:

[image]

В чем может быть проблема?
[Ссылка на предыдущий вопрос, где приведен код программы.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776890/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B/777034#777034)

```
X=zn;
double *aX = new double[j];
double *aKmp = new double[j];// тут во время отладки вылетает программа с ошибкой !
double *aKmpu = new double[j];
aX[0]=zn;
aKmp[0]=0;
aKmpu[0]=0;
for (j=1;j<1000;j++) {
    aX[j]=X/1000; 
}
```

Comment: В приведенном коде ошибки нет, приведите код использования, и желательно с указанием строки, на которой вылетает ошибка.

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: @Bearded Beaver Я привел ссылку на предыдущий вопрос, где приведен код программы )

Comment: @VTT да пробовал вылетает программа с ошибкой сразу после double *aKmp = new double [j];

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Comment: @VTT Ошибка либо "runtime error!", либо "Возникшая проблемам привела к прекращению работы программы"... j  начинается с 0 и изменяется до 999.

Comment: Это говорит о том, что вы ее не отлаживаете, а просто запускаете... Если бы она работала под дебаггером, то там бы было приглашение отладить, которое бы привело на сбойную строку.

Comment: Чему равно j? Должно быть 1000 или больше, иначе вы выделяете памяти меньше, то, к чему пытаетесь обратиться

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, я вам еще раз говорю, залейте код куда-нибудь, мы гадаем на кофейной гуще вместо отладки (отладки за вас, но это другой вопрос)

Comment: Код заливать никуда не надо, надо приводить в самом вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ Bearded Beaver  Да хорошо сейчас .... Но мне там целую инструкцию надо будет писать как запустить программу . Сейчас попробую залить

Comment: @VTT у него весь код минимальный и самодостаточный, так что его проще залить))

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Ага, такой минимальный и самодостаточный, что *"там целую инструкцию надо будет писать"*.

Comment: Всем спасибо графики вывелись без ошибок, когда я с верху поставил j=1000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В`aX` выделена память для одного элемента, а вы пытаетесь работать с ним как с массивом на тысячу элементов

```
X=zn;j=1;
double *aX = new double[j];
double *aKmp = new double[j];
double *aKmpu = new double[j];
aX[0]=zn;
aKmp[0]=0;
aKmpu[0]=0;
while (j<1000) {
    aX[j]=X/1000; //Вот здесь на первой итерации(j==1) должен валиться
   ...
    j+=1;
}
```

Comment: Я уже изменил это ....как ,приведу выше в вопросе сейчас .

Comment: Добавил как я изменил программу. Что я сделал не так ?

Comment: У вас в вопросе код из моего ответа и ошибка на которую я указал сохранена, приведите код из своей программы

Comment: Я привел в вопросе как я изменил программу :j=1; убрал и место while добавил for . Во время отладки программа перестает работать на строчке double *aKmp = new double[j];

Comment: Эти изменения ошибку сохранили. Если это точный код который работает у вас, то падать в этой строке может только если `j` не инициализирована.

Comment: По вашему мнению, как код надо изменить ?...... Сейчас попробую  j=999 и отладить

Comment: Не 999, а 1000, потому что индексы идут с нуля. (0,1,2 ... 999)

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Так как вы утверждаете, что ошибка происходит на строке `double *aKmp = new double[j];`, даже полное отсутствие кода после этой строки никак не должно влиять на ошибку.

Comment: @VTT Спасибо, что терпите мою тупость ....сейчас пробую

Comment: У меня получилось .... когда я поставил j=1000; аллилуйя

Comment: @IvanTriumphov ну да, вам же за эти два вопроса всего раза четыре сказали это сделать :)

Comment: @Bearded Beaver  Ну да доходит, как до жирафа. Сори. Зато отладкой научился пользоваться в Qt Creator.